# Building calculator app - When clicking the equals operator it just shows "0"

Tags: javascript, html, function

For some reason it is not calculating at all when I click the "=" operator. I assume it's some sort of problem with the "operate()" function. The only thing that happens when I click the equals operator is that is shows "0" from my ".result" in the html.

```js
const numberKeys = document.querySelectorAll('.number-key');
const operatorKeys = document.querySelectorAll('.operator-key');
const result = document.querySelector('.result');

let num1 = "";
let num2 = "";
let operator = "";
let isFirstNum = true;

function startingPoint() {
  result.innerHTML = "0";
  num1 = "";
  num2 = "";
  operator = "";
  isFirstNum = true;
}

function numDisplay() {
  numberKeys.forEach((key) => {
    key.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (isFirstNum) {
        num1 += key.innerHTML;
        result.innerHTML = num1;
      } else {
        num2 += key.innerHTML;
        result.innerHTML = num2;
      }
    });
  });
}

function setOperator() {
  operatorKeys.forEach((key) => {
    key.addEventListener("click", () => {
      operator = key.innerHTML;
      isFirstNum = false;
      operatorDisplay();
    });
  });
}

function operatorDisplay() {
  result.innerHTML = operator;
}

function clearDisplay() {
  const clearBtn = document.querySelector("#clear");
  clearBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    startingPoint();
  });
}

function operate() {
  let total = 0;

  switch (operator) {
    case '+':
      total = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);
      break;
    case '-':
      total = parseFloat(num1) - parseFloat(num2);
      break;
    case '*':
      total = parseFloat(num1) * parseFloat(num2);
      break;
    case '/':
      total = parseFloat(num1) / parseFloat(num2);
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Invalid operator');
      break;
  }

  result.innerHTML = total;
  num1 = total;
  num2 = "";
  operator = "";
  isFirstNum = true;
}

numDisplay();
setOperator();
clearDisplay();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}


/* Calculator styles */

.calculator {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

.display {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: stretch;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.result {
  font-size: 48px;
}

.keypad {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px;
}

.key {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: calc(25% - 20px);
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.key:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.key:active {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Responsive styles */

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .keypad {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .key {
    flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="main-container">
  <div class="calculator">
    <div class="display">
      <div class="result">0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="keypad">
      <button class="key number-key">1</button>
      <button class="key number-key">2</button>
      <button class="key number-key">3</button>
      <button class="key operator-key" id="addition">+</button>
      <button class="key number-key">4</button>
      <button class="key number-key">5</button>
      <button class="key number-key">6</button>
      <button class="key operator-key" id="subtract">-</button>
      <button class="key number-key">7</button>
      <button class="key number-key">8</button>
      <button class="key number-key">9</button>
      <button class="key operator-key" id="multiply">*</button>
      <button class="key number-key" id="zero">0</button>
      <button class="key" id="float">.</button>
      <button class="key" id="clear">C</button>
      <button class="key operator-key" id="backslash">/</button>
      <button class="key operator-key" id="equals">=</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<!-- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? How far did it get?

Comment: FYI, that's not a backslash. It's just a slash. I'd probably ID it for its purpose anyway, as "divide".

Comment: Your `oparate()` function does not get called at all, you should add an eventlistener to the equals button

Comment: Hey thanks @Samball. It no longer shows "0". I added an event listener for the equals button but instead of showing me the computed result it just shows "undefined" now. Any ideas?

Comment: It also prints "invalid operator" in the console every time I click the equal buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it! So the issue was that the = operator was not being recognized in the operate() function. This was because the = operator was not being stored as a value in the operator variable, since it is actually an equality comparison operator in JavaScript.

To fix this, I changed the = button's id to something other than equals, and updated the relevant line of code in the setOperator() function to use the new id value:

```
function setOperator() {
  operatorKeys.forEach((key) => {
    key.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (key.innerHTML === '=') {
        return;
      }

      operator = key.innerHTML;
      isFirstNum = false;
      operatorDisplay();
    });
  });
}
```

In this case, we changed the id value to equal. I also added an event listener for the equals key:

```
equalsKey.addEventListener('click', () => {
  operate(num1, num2, operator);
});
```